# Por que o label de texto não é alterado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes, variáveis-globais

Tenho a classe de uma tela, que contém um label de texto, o código carrega um xml contendo os objetos.

**tela.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import gi
import modulo_arquivos
import os

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

# diretorios dos arquivos
diretorio_exe = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
diretorio_proj = diretorio_exe + '/'
diretorio_tela = diretorio_proj + 'screens/tela_principal/tela_principal.glade'

class tela_principal():


    def carrega_arquivo_xml(self):


        self.tela_builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.tela_builder.add_from_file(diretorio_tela)

        self.janela = self.tela_builder.get_object("Janela")
        self.label_txt = self.tela_builder.get_object('txt_ps_atual01')


    def abre_tela(self):
        self.janela.show()

    def fecha_tela(self):
        self.janela.hide()


    def escreve_txt(self, texto):
        self.label_txt.set_text(texto))
```

E tenho um arquivo principal que cria a instancia da tela e manda abrir. No código principal tenho dois processos conforme o código abaixo:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#IMPORTS
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pipe
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

import tela

tela_principal = tela.tela_principal()
tela_principal.carrega_arquivo_xml()
tela_principal.abre_tela()

def escreve_texto(texto):
    tela_principal.escreve_txt(texto)

def interface_grafica(tx, rx):

    while True:

        Gtk.main_iteration_do(False)

        #escreve_texto('HELLO')

def comunicacao_serial(tx,rx):
    escreve_texto('HELLO2')




if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue1 = Queue()
    queue2 = Queue()

    p1 = Process(target=interface_grafica, args=(queue1, queue2,))
    p2 = Process(target=comunicacao_serial, args=(queue2, queue1,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

O problema é que o label só é modificado dentro da função interface gráfica, mas dentro da função comunicação não é alterada. Por que isso acontece e como resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade, é surpreendente o fato do label ser alterado do jeito que o código está, se você chamar a função  `escreve_texto` de dentro de `interface_grafica`.

Um "processo" é algo independente no nível do sistema operacional - nenhuma variável, janela, arquivo, ou outra coisa de um processo deveria ser visível de outro processo - a não ser que se usem mecanismos explícitos de compartilhamento de dados entre processos.  Há algumas regras de herança de recursos - em que, dependendo dos parâmetros usados para criar o processo filho, ele pode ter acesso a alguns recursos do processo pai.

Esse código na verdade tem 3 processos: o programa principal - e você cria um sub-processo apenas para gerenciar a interface gráfica, e outro apenas para a comunicação serial. A sua janela ficar aberta e não fechar com um erro ao ser chamado o `.main_iteration_do` é uma surpresa pra mim - significa que esse segundo processo na verdade teve acesso as estruturas de dados do GTK que estavam no primeiro processo (e isso aconteceu de forma implícita).

Bom - há algumas formas de resolver a abordagem aí; se você for manter a arquitetura de multi-processos, a forma recomendada seria criar queues (não dá pra ver como você cria as que estão aí, mas suponho que estejam corretas) - e passar *todos* os dados que você quer que apareçam na interface gráfica por meio dessas queues. Não adianta tentar chamar um método que acesse o GTK diretamente de outro processo - as variáveis, objetos, tudo o que está na tela, nem sequer existem no segundo processo.

Agora - a recomendação mesma aí seria *não*  usar essa arquitetura de subprocessos nesse programa.
Como você pode ver, a complexidade começa a aumentar (e você está tentando alterar um simples label) - a complexidade vai aumentar, *muito* mais se vocẽ tiver uqe responder a mais eventos na interface do que só alterar um label - vai ter que acabar criando uma função que lê a queue de eventos vinda do outro processo e despacha para funções locais - e para codificiar os eventos na queue, vai acabar desenvolvendo uma "mini-linguagem".

Um código com comunicação coma serial e itnerface GTK pode perfeitamente funcionar num único processo. Se vocẽ não quiser escrever o código da serial de forma um pouco mais complexa para ser não bloqueante, pode usar duas threads. (Mas aí lembrar sempre de não tentar chamar nenhuma funcionalidade do GTK de dentro da segunda thread - apenas colocar dados em estruturas de que são consumidas em funções dentro da primeira thread - você pode usar queues, ou mesmo listas de Python para isso).

De qualquer forma, você já tem resolvido o problema do GTK não te dar controle do programa ao chamar o `.main_iteration_do` em vez do `.mainloop`. Tudo o que você precisa fazer é, no mesmo ponto em que repetidamente chama esse método do GTK, também chame a função para interagir com a porta serial - e, claro, mudar a função da serial para ter um timeout de zero  - dessa forma o programa não vai ficar parado esperando ter bytes disponíveis.

```
...

def main():
    dados_lidos = b""
    dados_a_escrever = b""
    while True:
         # processa eventos da interface gráfica:
         if Gtk.main_iteration_do(False):
              # a interface gráfica recebeu um evento de sair:
              break
         # realiza a comunicação serial:
         comunicacao_serial(dados_a_escrever)
         # processa os dados lidos da serial, 
         # como está tudo no mesmo processo e mesma thread, essa
         # funçao vai poder alterar a interface gráfica
         # sem problemas
         dados_a_escrever = processa(dados_lidos)
         # repete.


def comunicacao_serial(dados_a_escrever):
     if dados_a_escrever:
         serial.write(dados_a_escrever)
     return serial.read(10000)

def setup():
    serial = Pyseral.Serial(..., timeout=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup()
    main()
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta tão esclarecedora!